# How to disable selection for some items in Windows Phone 8.1 ListView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have a `ListView` in my Windows Phone 8.1 in which multiple items can be selected. A few items are not selectable in it. I have defined a `DataTemplate` Selector for both kinds of items. The class which i am using for binding has an `IsSelectable` property which determines which `DataTemplate` is to be used.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Multiple">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="KeyValueDataTemplate">
        <utils:KeyValueTemplateSelector HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding}">
            <utils:KeyValueTemplateSelector.NotSelectable>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- some controls -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </utils:KeyValueTemplateSelector.NotSelectable>
            <utils:KeyValueTemplateSelector.Selectable>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- some controls -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </utils:KeyValueTemplateSelector.Selectable>
        </utils:KeyValueTemplateSelector>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Using the `SelectionMode="Multiple"` option displays a `CheckBox` beside every item automatically. I need to hide the `CheckBox` for items which are not selectable. I tried editing the `ListViewItem` `Style` and binding the checkbox `Visibility`  `IsSelectable`(using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`). But it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In any part of your DataTemplate set this property:

```
local:SelectorHelper.IsItemSelectionEnabled="{Binding IsSelectable}"
```

Example:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid local:SelectorHelper.IsItemSelectionEnabled="{Binding IsSelectable}">
            <!-- -->
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And here is my SelectorHelper:

```
public static class SelectorHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsItemSelectionEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsItemSelectionEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(SelectorHelper), new PropertyMetadata(true, IsItemSelectionEnabledChanged));


    public static void SetIsItemSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool value)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(IsItemSelectionEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsItemSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(IsItemSelectionEnabledProperty);
    }


    private static void IsItemSelectionEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)d;
        var selectorItem = XamlTreeHelper.FindParent<SelectorItem>(frameworkElement);
        if (selectorItem != null)
        {
            selectorItem.IsEnabled = GetIsItemSelectionEnabled(frameworkElement);
        }
        else
        {
            frameworkElement.Loaded -= OnSelectableItemLoaded;
            frameworkElement.Loaded += OnSelectableItemLoaded;
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelectableItemLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var selectorItem = FindParent<SelectorItem>(frameworkElement);
        if (selectorItem != null)
        {
            selectorItem.IsEnabled = GetIsItemSelectionEnabled(frameworkElement);
        }
    }

    private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var currentObject = child;
        do
        {
            currentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentObject);
            var parent = currentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                return parent;
            }
        } while (currentObject != null);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above approach and it successfully disables selection for that item but CheckBox is still visible. I want to hide the CheckBox if selection is disabled.

Comment: Oh, i forgot how it looks on Windows phone (checkboxes near the ListView...).
Sorry, i don't know how to remove this checkboxes.